# Making my category headers smaller

Tags: categories, headers

I have placed my categories as my header and I have 7 of them. However, they break into 2 lines. See picture below: 
[image]

Where do I go to make it smaller?

Comment: Hello. Although this is not a wordpress-related question and should be asked in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) community, you can edit the header's size in the `style.css` file in your template's directory.

Comment: I recommend two google searches 2) "how to style wordpress menus with CSS and style.css" and 2)  "how to make CSS Media queries in wordpress" and

Comment: or you could provide your site code and link?